# Constructing a simplicial map from a diagram

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff

I am trying to read Goerss and Jardine's book (Simplicial Homotopy Theory) and in the proof of Theorem 7.10 (in chapter 1), they claim that there is a simplicial homotopy $\Delta^n\times\Delta^1\to\Delta^n$ given by the diagram:

$$\begin{array}{ccccccc}
0&\to &0&\to &\dots&\to &0\\
\downarrow &&\downarrow &&\dots &&\downarrow\\
0&\to &1&\to&\dots&\to &n
\end{array}$$
I am unsure how this actually defines a simplicial map at all. Is there a way to construct a simplicial map from this diagram?

If it helps, the simplicial map is (I think) supposed to be a contraction from the identity to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simply contracts $\Delta^n$ onto the $0$-vertex. The diagram you draw encodes the following map $\mathbf{n} \times\mathbf{1} \to \mathbf{n}$ where elements $(m,0)\mapsto 0$ and $(m,1) \mapsto m$. This map induces
$$
\Delta^n\times \Delta^1 = \operatorname{hom}_\Delta(-, \mathbf{n}) \times \operatorname{hom}_\Delta(-, \mathbf{1}) \cong \operatorname{hom}_\Delta(-,\mathbf{n} \times\mathbf{1}) \to \operatorname{hom}_\Delta(-, \mathbf{n}) = \Delta^n.
$$ 
It could help if you check the effect after geometric realization. This is the standard contracting homotopy of $|\Delta^n|$ to $|\Delta^0| = *$. Write a formula for this homotopy and compare!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It makes the diagram very clear.

Comment: Perhaps there is a typo in this books’s definition of homotopy, but wouldn’t this homotopy actually be from $0\to\Delta^n$? Certainly the restriction of this homotopy to $\Delta^n\times\{0\}$ is 0, right? At least this is true if the homotopy is defined by $(f,g)\to\varphi(f,g)$, where $\varphi$ is the map $\mathbf{n}\times\mathbf{1}\to\mathbf{n}$.

Comment: I guess, but that seems irrelevant to me.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that a map between products of simplices is nothing more than a map of the corresponding partially ordered sets. Thus what is given here is the values of the desired map of the vertices of $\Delta^n\times \Delta^1$, which uniquely determine the map.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach. Define the natural transformation $H:\Delta^n\times\Delta^1\twoheadrightarrow\Delta^n$ whose component at $\mathbf{m}$ is given by
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
H_\mathbf{m}:\Delta^n(\mathbf{m})\times\Delta^1(\mathbf{m})  &\twoheadrightarrow& \Delta^n(\mathbf{m})\\
(\alpha,\beta)&\mapsto&\alpha\cdot\beta
\end{array}
$$
where $\alpha\cdot\beta:\mathbf{m}\rightarrow\mathbf{n}$ is the nondecreasing map given by pointwise multiplication. The natural transformation $H$ is a simplicial homotopy from the zero map $0:\Delta^n\rightarrow\Delta^n$ to the identity map $1_{\Delta^n}:\Delta^n\rightarrow\Delta^n$.